# How can I improve the performance of this CIFilter chain?

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter

I am creating my context (with an EAGLContext) and filters externally and reusing them, however I still am finding it to take about 1 second per UIImage to process with this filter chain-- not to mention that despite the fact that is running on a background thread, the main thread totally lags and my frame rate suffers.  I've also tried using the software rendering option, but can't really tell much of a difference.

```
+(CGImageRef *)cgImageForImage:(UIImage *)image
                  rotatedByHue:(CGFloat)hue
                    saturation:(CGFloat)saturation
                        matrix:(NSArray *)matrix
                       context:(CIContext *)context
                     hueFilter:(CIFilter *)hueFilter
              saturationFilter:(CIFilter *)saturationFilter
                  matrixFilter:(CIFilter *)matrixFilter {
    CIImage *sourceCore = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];
    CIImage *resultCore = nil;

    if (hue != 0.0f) {
        [hueFilter setDefaults];
        [hueFilter setValue:sourceCore forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        [hueFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:hue] forKey:kCIInputAngleKey];
        resultCore = [hueFilter outputImage];
    }

    if (saturation != 1.0f) {
        [saturationFilter setDefaults];
        [saturationFilter setValue:(resultCore ? resultCore : sourceCore) forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        [saturationFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:saturation] forKey:kCIInputSaturationKey];
        resultCore = [saturationFilter outputImage];
    }

    if (matrix) {
        [matrixFilter setDefaults];
        [matrixFilter setValue:(resultCore ? resultCore : sourceCore) forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        [matrixFilter setValue:[self vectorForMatrixRow:matrix[0]] forKey:@"inputRVector"];
        [matrixFilter setValue:[self vectorForMatrixRow:matrix[1]] forKey:@"inputGVector"];
        [matrixFilter setValue:[self vectorForMatrixRow:matrix[2]] forKey:@"inputBVector"];
        [matrixFilter setValue:[self vectorForMatrixRow:matrix[3]] forKey:@"inputAVector"];
        [matrixFilter setValue:[self vectorForMatrixRow:matrix[4]] forKey:@"inputBiasVector"];
        resultCore = [matrixFilter outputImage];
    }

    return [context createCGImage:resultCore fromRect:[resultCore extent]];
}

+(CIVector *)vectorForMatrixRow:(NSArray *)row {
  return [CIVector vectorWithX:[row[0] floatValue] Y:[row[1] floatValue] Z:[row[2] floatValue] W:[row[3] floatValue]];
}
```

Since I am using an EAGLContext, would there be a benefit to rendering each outputImage to a GLKView ?

Comment: Any time you say `[context createCGImage:resultCore fromRect:[resultCore extent]]` there is going to be a lag; this is a time-consuming call. Any time you want to apply CIFilter in real time, you should certainly be using GLKView if you can.

Comment: BTW another trick is just to drop frames if you have to in order to keep up.

Comment: @matt sorry-- not sure I am understanding when you say drop frames?  Basically, this is for a game, I am trying to process image textures before the game starts, and this image processing is happening in a  background thread while the UI is showing a spinner animating-- but the spinner totally freezes while this is happening.  Plus, there are 7 images that are being processed and its taking about 7 seconds which is really awful.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were trying to display the results of every rendering in real time.  It sounds like your problems are elsewhere. Use Instruments to find out what's happening.  You may have threading issues.

Comment: Also, I find it a little odd that you are using EAGLContext without a GLKView. Shouldn't you just be using a CIContext? Make sure that you create it only once, as it is the creation that is most expensive.

Comment: @matt my game is using openGL so I had a context available I thought I'd try using it since I read it would have better performance.  Honestly, I couldn't tell a difference between GPU or CPU.  For the moment, I abandoned my approach and instead am processing the images one time and saving them to the device's file system.